# Visual Studio 2019 is not running other .cpp files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, execution

[image]

New to VS and C++. I'm trying to run code for source file "test2.cpp." However, every time I run the program, VS always runs "Simple-letter-with-ASCII-number.cpp."

I'm on the "test2.cpp" window, but the file never runs. I need assistance in running "test2.cpp" and not "Simple-letter-with-ASCII-number.cpp," **without deleting** any .cpp files, if possible.

- Both .cpp files have different labeled main()
- Both .cpp files are in the same project

Comment: Move `main()` to `test2.cpp` and it will "run".

Comment: alright... we just found the similar situation.... :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your project will call main() when it runs.  When you said “differently labeled main()” I am assuming you changed a main() to test2main().  Just change the main function you want to run to be main() and your program should run when you recompile.

Answer (score 1):

The screenshot looks like Visual Studio 2019, not Visual Studio Code.

**Both .cpp files are part of the project.**

If you want to keep only `test2.cpp`, then remove the other from the project (right-click on it, select "Remove").

Then build (Ctrl-Shift-B) and run (F5).